# Android EditText cannot focus when the keyboard is showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a problem on the EditText. I cannot show all the EditText field when the soft keyboard is showing, just like the following image:

[image: Screenshot]

And the following is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dip"
    android:focusable="true" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/password_listing"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/new_service"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="10dip" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/l_service_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/service_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/service_name"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/servicename"
        android:layout_width="180dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:hint=""
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:focusable="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/l_username"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/username"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="180dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:hint=""
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:focusable="true" />     
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/l_pwd"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pwdset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/pwd_txt"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pwd_set"
        android:layout_width="180dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:hint=""
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:focusable="true" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layout_3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/selectmsg_txt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/selectmsg"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/app_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnWidth="60dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_addpwd"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20dip" />
    </LinearLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Since I want it auto-hidden the soft keyboard when I enter this activity, so I added this into my activity:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

What is the problem with my layout xml?

Comment: maybe u shud try adding a scrollview to ur total layout.

Comment: I have tried this, but it still not work. 
I have another layout with no scroll view, it can also auto scroll up to show the EditText.

Answer (score 0):

use a scroll view and also add following in the activity tag in manifest file:

```
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: It said that I cannot add ScrollView because I have a GridView. Also, it can only have one child for the ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code snippet in your manifest file :

```
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

Comment: I tested both [android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"] & the above [android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"]. Both not work.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me is this:

```
EditText et = new EditText(); //or whatever way you use to fetch the object
et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

Hope it'll help you as well